# Only the last XMLHttpRequest returns data

Tags: javascript, xml, file, xmlhttprequest, filereader

I am retrieving some files from the server and adding them to a file[] so I can read them later. However, when I read multiple images, I only get the data from the last image. The rest are null.

```
      var files = [];
      var imageURLs = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < image.length; i++){
        imageURLs[i] = image[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "?t="+ Math.random();
      }

      for(var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", imageURLs[i]);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.customURL = imageURLs[i];
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            var index = imageURLs.indexOf(this.responseURL);
            imageURLs.splice(index, 1);
            var arrayBuffer = xhr.response;
            files.push(new File([arrayBuffer], this.responseURL.toString().split('#').shift().split('?').shift().split('/').pop()));
            if(imageURLs.length == 0){
              makeFileList(files);
            }
          }
        };
      }
```

I am getting the links from an XML file.

--------------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------

I fixed it by making a seperate array of XMLHttpRequest's and processing them individually like so:

```
      var imageURLs = [];
      var files = [];
      var xhrs = []; //THIS IS NEW

      for(var i = 0; i < image.length; i++){
        imageURLs[i] = image[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "?t="+ Math.random();
        //I initialized them here
        xhrs[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //I set their callbacks
        xhrs[i].onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            var index = imageURLs.indexOf(this.responseURL);
            imageURLs.splice(index, 1);
            var arrayBuffer = this.response;
            files.push(new File([arrayBuffer], this.responseURL.toString().split('#').shift().split('?').shift().split('/').pop()));
            if(imageURLs.length == 0){
              makeFileList(files);
            }
          }
        };
      }

      for(var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++){
        //I sent them
        xhrs[i].open("GET", imageURLs[i]);
        xhrs[i].responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhrs[i].customURL = imageURLs[i];
        xhrs[i].send();
      }
```

Comment: All your AJAX calls are getting made, but because you put them in a loop, only the last one is the one you are storing the results of because your are re-initializing your `xhr` variable upon each iteration. So, there is only one `xhr` with one callback instead of many `xhr`s and many callbacks. Instead, don't put them in a loop.

Also, the `onreadystatechange` event callback should always be configured prior to invoking `.send` as there is a chance that the AJAX response could come back before the callback gets registered.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!